# Взаимодействие с классом, унаследованным от UITableViewCell в xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Здравия. Есть у меня 2 класса. Один унаследован от UITableViewCell, второй от UIViewController (с ).

В первом классе есть метод, который меняет изображение кнопки при нажатии (сама кнопка находится в ячейке).

```
-(void)method:(int)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    UIImage *checkSel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];

    if (sender == 0) {
        [self.checkButton setBackgroundImage:checkSel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"checkReq0"];
        checkReq0 = YES;
        self.checkLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        NSLog(@"CheckOn1 OK");
        }
```

Во втором классе я пытаюсь вызвать этот метод, который должен менять изображение на той же самой кнопке, когда я нажимаю на другую кнопку (она находится вне ячейки)

```
-(IBAction)secondButton:(id)sender {
    firstClass *object = [[firstClass alloc] init];
    [object method];

}
```

B сам метод срабатывает в целом, проверял с помощью NSLog, но поставленную задачу не выполняет никак. В хедерах тоже вроде все прописано как надо.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо

Comment: Вы создаете новый экземпляр и вызываете его метод. Вам нужно вызывать для уже имеющегося. Судя по описанию, подход можно изменить. Я правильно понял, что Вы хотите поменять изображение кнопки в ячейке как при нажатии кнопки внутри ячейки, так и кнопки извне?

Comment: @VAndrJ Правильно поняли. У меня метод же динамический, как его вызвать, не создавая экземпляр класса?

Comment: @Bandicoot вам нужно взять ссылку на на ячейку из таблицы через `cellForRowAtIndexPath` и уже у этого экземпляра вызывать ваш метод

Comment: @andrey-iskamov попробовал сделать как вы сказали, но так и не смог добиться желаемого. Видимо, я чего-то не понял

Answer (score 1):

У вас метод `metod` принимает параметр типа `int`, но при вызове этого метода, вы туда ничего не передаете.

Думаю, что код должен выглядеть так:

```
- (IBAction)secondButton:(UIButton *)sender { 
     firstClass *object = [[firstClass alloc] init]; 
     [object method:sender.tag]; 
}
```

Comment: А как нужно? Покажите на примере.

Comment: Очень странно, что именно вы ответили на мой комментарий! Я бы переделал secondButton так: - (IBAction)secondButton:(UIButton *)sender {
        firstClass *object = [[firstClass alloc] init];
        [object method:sender.tag];
        
    }

Comment: @0xdb я так понял, что это вы поставили -1 ответу. Можете аргументировать?

Comment: Нет, не я. Не могу аргументировать.

Answer (score 0):

Таким способом `firstClass *object = [[firstClass alloc] init];` вы создаете новый экземпляр ячейки, не находящийся в таблице, соответственно вызов метода у данного экземпляра не приводит к желаемому результату.

Чтобы вызвать метод у нужной ячейки, её нужно достать из таблицы (tableView).
Для этого создадим indexPath ('адрес' ячейки в таблице), где `row` - номер ячейки в секции, `section` - номер секции в tableView:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

Далее мы обращаемся к таблице, чтобы получить нужный нам экземпляр ячейки:

```
firstClass *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Теперь мы можем вызывать нужный метод:

```
[cell method];
```